# Highslide iframe on close and reopen doesn't update content

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am using Highslide and it is working well, except when I try to reopen a highslide popup with new content.  I actually don't need it to reopen, but since its the same contentId, it does.  The content is not being updated though.  Here is the code:

```
function doSomething() {
  //Changes to fileExistList (removed for simplicity)
  var newHTML = $('fileExistList').clone(true); //Cloning div as Highslide removes it
  $(newHTML).id = 'fileExistList2'; //Change cloned divs id
  $('fileExistList').insert({ //add cloned div to page
    before: newHTML 
  });
  hs.htmlExpand(null, { contentId: 'fileExistList2', align:'center' });
}
```

The first time it is called, it displays correctly, but all the times after that until refresh displays the initial popup content and not the updated content.  I am using iframes for the Highslide popups.

Anyone have any ideas how to modify this to open with the updated content?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highslide has a few configuration options and one is preserveContent, which you need set to false for HTML content.  This wasn't the only thing that I had to do to make it work.  I had to check the hs.clones object and remove the id of the HTML content I was copying.  This forces highslide to get the updated id content.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to late to answer, but best way is to redirect your page (page that show in iframe) after you've done your job.

Something like this:

```
Page1->Enter your data->Redirect to itself->Page1
```

I always do this in my works and it's always working.